# How to send fax with AT Command in C#?

Tags: c#, at-command, fax

I want to send fax in serial port with AT Command in C#.
I am reading [this pdf](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/modem/AT/wic/command/reference/atwic.pdf) learning for send or receive a fax with AT Commands.
But i have problems.
For example this is my method for send command to Serial Port:

```
        void WriteData(string command)
        {
            maintxt.Text += "Send: " + command + Environment.NewLine;
            port.Write(command + Environment.NewLine);
            var read = port.ReadExisting();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(read))
                maintxt.Text += "Read: " + port.ReadExisting();
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

and example for send fax:

```
    WriteData("AT+FCLASS=1;+IFC=2,2");//command for set fax class and flow control

    WriteData("at+vcid=2");//command for set caller id

    WriteData("ATDT333222111");//command for call
```

after i send these commands to modem:

step 1: modem is calling

step 2: answer call

step 3: report me "CONNECT"

and i don't understanding TSI And CSI frame for send or receive data in fax modem(in pdf page of 156):

```
AT+FRH=3
<TSI frame data>
<DLE><ETX>
<DCS frame data>
<DLE><ETX>
```

how to use these commands?

Comment: Writing your own fax driver and hoping it will work with any modem is a bit like building a submarine in your basement.  It's not like you couldn't get it done but the odds that you'll get it up the stairs and keep it afloat just are not very good.  Project + Properties, COM tab, tick "Microsoft Fax Service Extended COM Type Library".  The programming guide [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for replay.but i don't want use components.because those are not resolved my Requirement. for example i want to send dial pad number after answered call that microsoft fax not support this.

Comment: or microsoft fax is very complex for programming server and configuration in client and limit for me...

Comment: Hmya, you're pretty much on your own when you have requirements like that.  An obvious way to see how the submarine was built is to use a serial port monitor utility and find out how the built-in Fax service does it.

Comment: I used serial port monitor and read at command log for windows fax and venta fax and other apps. but i don't understanding that how to send or receive data (TSI or CSI)

Answer (score -1):

I did some debugging for Modem and send the fax via Windows Fax and i got this data, see below maybe this can help. I am also creating the dll to send fax.

```
AT&FS0=0E0V1Q0

OK

AT 

OK

ATS7=60&D3&K4\Q1\J0

OK

ATX4M1L3

OK

AT+FCLASS=1

AT 

OK

OK

ATDT xxxxxxx

CONNECT

ÿ  ­ÿ  ­ÿ  ­
\
AT+FRH=3

CONNECT

ÿ @4816654             Ÿí  

OK

AT+FRH=3

CONNECT

ÿ €ÿ €ÿ €ÿ €

AT+FTH=3

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ C                 xaF  

CONNECT

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ ƒ  

OK

OK

OK

AT+FTM=145

CONNECT

CONNECT

OK

OK

OK

AT+FRH=3

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ „ê}  
OK
ÿ „ê}  
OK
ÿ „ê}  

OK

AT+FTM=146

CONNECT

CONNECT

€ € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ a € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € d €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € €˜T¢\DŽT±Šò™ç     "L„‰  & D˜ OË  â2ÈAXæ aâ:W
€“JUÈQU%?ß 
) É É  [¦Cˆ ’AÊ)  " ’H €þ—$Y–eY–eI–ä%YV9€ € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € €˜T¢\DŽT±Šò™ç     "L„‰  & D˜ OË  â2ÈAXæ aâ:W
€“JUÈQU%?ß 
) É É  [¦Cˆ ’AÊ)  " ’H €þ—$Y–eY–eI–ä%YV9€ € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € €˜T¢\DŽT±Šò™ç     "L„‰  & D˜ OË  â2ÈAXæ aâ:W
€“JUÈQU%?ß 
) É É  [¦Cˆ ’AÊ)  " ’H €þ—$Y–eY–eI–ä%YV9€ € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € € €e³ € € €˜T¢\DŽT±Šò™ç     "L„‰  & D˜ OË  â2ÈAXæ aâ:W
€“JUÈQU%?ß 
) É É  [¦Cˆ ’AÊ)  " ’H €þ—$Y–eY–eI–ä%YV9

OK

OK

OK

AT+FTH=3

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ /  
OK

OK

OK

AT+FRH=3

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ Œ¢ñ  

OK

ÿ Œ¢ñ  

OK

ÿ Œ¢ñ  

OK

AT+FTH=3

CONNECT

CONNECT

ÿ û  

OK

OK

OK

ATH0

AT

ATH0

OK

OK

OK

OK

OK

OK

OK

OK

ATH0

OK

OK

AT+FCLASS=0

AT

OK

OK

AT

OK

OK

AT

OK

AT&FE0V1&C1&D2S95=47S0=0

OK 

ATS7=60L3M1&K3N1X4 

OK

ATS0=0

OK
```